# Envío de formulario por AJAX con JSON hacia Java controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, model-view-controller

Tengo este código, lo que hace es recorrer todo los input del formulario y armar un `data` para enviarlo por AJAX.

```
var data = {};
var form = $('#formEdit').serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
data[form[i]['name']] = form[i]['value'];
}
```

Pregunta HTML:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <div class="form-input">
        <div class="input-text">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion321" name="seccion32" value="1" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        1. El nivel de producción, servicios o ventas va a ser igual o menor al de este año debido a una reducción de la demanda.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion322" name="seccion32" value="2" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        2. El nivel de producción, servicios o ventas va a ser igual o menor al de este año debido a una mayor competencia.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion323" name="seccion32" value="3" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        3. Disminución de capital de trabajo, capacidad instalada y/o líneas de financiamiento.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion324" name="seccion32" value="4" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        4. Introducción de nuevas tecnologías / Cambios en los procesos productivos / Reestructuración / Reingeniería.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion325" name="seccion32" value="5" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        5. Tercerización de los servicios / Fusión de empresas / Cierre, liquidación de la empresa.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion326" name="seccion32" value="6" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        6. Legislación laboral limita la contratación.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion327" name="seccion32" value="50" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        7. El nivel de producción, servicios o ventas han sido afectadas por la pandemia (COVID - 19)</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-6"><input type="checkbox" id="seccion328" name="seccion32" value="7" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
                        8. Otras (especificar)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" path="demandaForm.motivoadicional" class="form-control" maxlength="150" id="seccion328_o" name="seccion328_o" disabled="">
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, todo el formulario se guarda en `data`.

Tengo una pregunta donde hay varios checkbox, las personas pueden marcar como mínimo uno o si quieren varios, entonces se presenta en problema. El código mostrado arriba arma para esta pregunta:

- en caso marque varios checkbox: `"seccion32": ["1","2","3"]`
- en caso marque solo uno : `"seccion32": "1"`

Entonces cuando llega al Java controller no diferencia qué parámetro elegir.

`String[] razon32 = request.getParameterValues("seccion32");`

De esta forma solo me funciona cuando llega un array, pero cuando solo llega un valor (es el caso donde marca solo un checkbox) el try catch me marca error cuando hago un `razon32.length`.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para poner un ejemplo de cómo aparecen los checkboxes en el formulario.

Comment: Hola @Triby, se añadió el html de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar el objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) para generar automáticamente la información que vas a enviar por AJAX, pero necesitas hacer que los campos que tienen el mismo nombre sean tratados como arreglos y solo hay que agregar corchetes en el nombre, por ejemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="seccion321" name="seccion32[]" value="1" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
<input type="checkbox" id="seccion322" name="seccion32[]" value="2" onchange="revcantcheck32(this)">
```

Debes hacerlo con todos los campos que compartan nombre y, finalmente, creas el objeto, teniendo en cuenta que jQuery usa el índice 0 para referirse al elemento HTML del selector especificado:

```
let data = new FormData($('#formEdit')[0]);
```

Esto a a incluir todos los campos que pertenecen al formulario y queda listo para enviar en la petición AJAX.